Does Angular Material 3 have css helper classes for margin/padding, flexbox, etc
Is there a built-in CSS helper classes for margin/padding, flexbox, etc. in Angular Material 3?
I see that Vuetify, Tailwind, Bootstrap have lots of helper classes (e.g. px-4, ma-6, mx-auto, etc.). Does Angular Material have something similar?
Any recommendations on how to avoid creating all these classes manually in Angular 18 + Material 3 site are welcome.

I am not sure it does, but if you want to use only the utility classes, you can experiment by importing only the utility classes and whatever classes you need, so that they can be used along with angular material.
There will not be a need to import the entire bootstrap but just the essentials you need.
_utilities.scss
We can import inside angular.json
      "options": {
        "assets": [],
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "browser": "src/main.ts",
        "outputPath": "dist/demo",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": ["src/global_styles.css", "node_modules/dist/scss/_utilities.scss"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"
      }


Angular does not offer css helper classes like the ones you mentioned below.
Just like you mentioned, developers may prefer to use Tailwind, Bootstrap or another, since these are framework independent.
If you want, you can include these in the angular project like a regular dependency.
In the Angular Guide's section, you can find how to customize typography, elevation and components, amongs others.
